# HSQL system memory Usage increasing

Tags: java, memory-leaks, hsqldb

I Hope that anyone will help me.

I am using hsqlDB, and my problem is
 The system memory(res) is constantly increasing  as belowed (1.6G)

```
  PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                          
  27961 root      20   0 3973m  1.6g  11m S  2.0 10.0  30:56.44 java
```

I 'm using HSQL DB as Server Mode and 
The overall amount of data is almost unchanged
Since continuous registration and deletion are performed
with spring boot batch scheduller.

I configure  JVM heap size  like that (-Xms1500m -Xmx1500m )
What is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

.

Comment: Use a tool such as Java VisualVM to find out how much memory is actually in use.

Answer (score 0):

In case of HSQL the tables are not CACHED by default, they are kept in memory, which could be one of the reasons why the memory keeps on increasing.

Your configuration should look something like :

```
 jdbc:hsqldb:file:${jar.path};
 hsqldb.write_delay=false;
 hsqldb.large_data=true;
 hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;
```